# Table not formatting correctly on safari

Tags: php, html, safari

I have the following php code, which gathers data from a database, and displays it in a table. It works fine when used in chrome, But is not working properly, i.e, the border, rows etc.. are not being displayed, like the table tag itself is being disregarded. Here is the code, I have.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Reviews List. </title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include 'settings.php';

        if (!isset($dbc)){
            $dbc = new mysqli(DB_HOST , DB_USER , DB_PASSWORD , DB_NAME) or die("Cannot connect to the database.");
        }
        $query = "SELECT * FROM reviews";
        $result = $dbc->query($query) or die ("Cannot query");
    ?>
        <table id="review_table" border="1" width="1">
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $row['id'];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $row['pid'];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $row['publish'];
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }       
    ?>
        </table>
</body>
```

Here are the screen shots of the page viewed in safari and in chrome.

Safari: [image]

I did try to click on the toggle formatting button, which did nothing.

Chrome: [image]

Comment: `width="1"` what else to expect?

Comment: Purely css issue, chrome / firefox / IE / safari does some things differently, but as Hanky Panky said,  a width of 1 is not a lot.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky,  I tried removing that tag, and changing it to width = "10", still no change.

Answer (score 1):

Remove border and width from table tag and add this css instead.

```
#review_table {
  border: 1px solid #000;  
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#review_table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: While it works, can you mention why my original plain html did not?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<tbody>` tag